# NSDate returns wrong date from database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have an application that user can order some items and by confirming the order the date of the order is saved and inserted in a sqlite database.

Then later the user can see the order list and the order date and there's an option that user can delete the orders up to whatever date they choose.

Up to this part there's no problem at all, when I select the orders to be shown the date which was returned by database is correct.

The problem occurs when the user wants to remove orders based of the date they choose in the date picker, at this point the date I'm getting from my order object is always before the correct date, for example:

> -Order date is 2011/12/20 14:24:23 +0000
>   -the order date shown to user is the same as above
>   -the order date when I want to compare dates together is 2011/12/19 14:24:23 +0000

any ideas?

edit:

```
#import "OrderListViewController.h"

@implementation OrderListViewController

@synthesize newOrderTabelView, transferedOrderTableView, salesOrderArr;
@synthesize newOrderTableViewController, transferedOrderViewController,salesOrder;
@synthesize newOrderTableViewHeader, transferedOrderTableViewHeader, datePicker,isPickerHidden;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        isPickerHidden=YES;
        [self initializeTableData];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [newOrderTabelView release];
    [transferedOrderTableView release];
    [newOrderTableViewController release];
    [transferedOrderViewController release];
    [salesOrderArr release];
    [newOrderTableViewController release];
    [transferedOrderViewController release];
    [salesOrder release];
    [datePicker release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
-(void)editSaleOrderForEditButton
{
    YourCartViewController *yourCartViewController=[[YourCartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourCartViewController" bundle:nil];
    yourCartViewController.title=@"Felton";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourCartViewController animated:YES];
    [yourCartViewController release];
}
-(IBAction)deleteOrderButton_Tapped
{
    if(isPickerHidden)
    {
        datePicker.hidden=NO;
        isPickerHidden=NO;
    }
    else if(!isPickerHidden)
    {
        NSDate* pickerDate = [datePicker date];
        datePicker.hidden=YES;
        isPickerHidden=YES;
        for(SalesOrder* order in salesOrderArr)
    {
        NSDate* orderDate = order.Date;
        /*if([orderDate earlierDate:pickerDate])
        {
            order.isDeleted = YES;
        }*/
        switch([orderDate compare:pickerDate])
        {
            case NSOrderedAscending:
                order.isDeleted = YES;
                break;
            case NSOrderedSame:
                order.isDeleted = YES;
                break;
            case NSOrderedDescending:break;
        }
        KDSDataSalesOrder* tSaleOrder = [[KDSDataSalesOrder alloc] init];
        [tSaleOrder updateSaleOrderIsDeleted:order];
        [tSaleOrder release];
    }
    [self reloadNewOrderTable];
}
}
-(void)initializeTableData
{
    KDSAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    KDSDataSalesOrder *dataSalesOrder=[[KDSDataSalesOrder alloc] init];
    NSArray* tNewSalesOrderArr=[dataSalesOrder selectSalesOrdersforSalesPerson:appDelegate.loggedInSalesPerson IsUploaded:NO IsDeleted:NO];
    self.salesOrderArr=tNewSalesOrderArr;
    [dataSalesOrder release];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    datePicker.hidden = YES;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if(newOrderTableViewController == nil)
    {
        NewOrderTableViewController *tNewOrderTableViewController = [[NewOrderTableViewController alloc] init];
    self.newOrderTableViewController = tNewOrderTableViewController;
    self.newOrderTableViewController.orderListViewController=self;
    [tNewOrderTableViewController release];
}
if(transferedOrderViewController == nil)
{
    TransferedOrderTableViewController *tTransferedOrderTableViewController = [[TransferedOrderTableViewController alloc] init];
    self.transferedOrderViewController = tTransferedOrderTableViewController;
    [tTransferedOrderTableViewController release];
}

[newOrderTabelView setDataSource:self.newOrderTableViewController];
[newOrderTabelView setDelegate:self.newOrderTableViewController];

[transferedOrderTableView setDataSource:self.transferedOrderViewController];
[transferedOrderTableView setDelegate:self.transferedOrderViewController];

self.newOrderTableViewController.view = self.newOrderTableViewController.tableView;
self.transferedOrderViewController.view = self.transferedOrderViewController.tableView;

UIView *NewOrdeertableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(newOrderTabelView.frame.origin.x, newOrderTabelView.frame.origin.y-30, self.newOrderTabelView.frame.size.width, 30)];
NewOrdeertableHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0196 green:0.513 blue:0.949 alpha:1.0];

UILabel *NewOrderTableHeaderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, self.newOrderTabelView.frame.size.width/2, 21)];
NewOrderTableHeaderLabel.text = @"New Order";
NewOrderTableHeaderLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
NewOrderTableHeaderLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
NewOrderTableHeaderLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
[NewOrdeertableHeaderView addSubview:NewOrderTableHeaderLabel];
newOrderTableViewHeader = NewOrdeertableHeaderView;
[self.view addSubview:newOrderTableViewHeader];

UIView *TransferedOrdertableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(transferedOrderTableView.frame.origin.x, transferedOrderTableView.frame.origin.y-30, self.transferedOrderTableView.frame.size.width, 30)];
TransferedOrdertableHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0196 green:0.513 blue:0.949 alpha:1.0];

UILabel *TransferedOrderTableHeaderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, self.transferedOrderTableView.frame.size.width/2, 21)];
TransferedOrderTableHeaderLabel.text = @"Transfered Order";
TransferedOrderTableHeaderLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
TransferedOrderTableHeaderLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
TransferedOrderTableHeaderLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
[TransferedOrdertableHeaderView addSubview:TransferedOrderTableHeaderLabel];
transferedOrderTableViewHeader = TransferedOrdertableHeaderView;
[self.view addSubview:transferedOrderTableViewHeader];

[NewOrdeertableHeaderView release];
[NewOrderTableHeaderLabel release];
[TransferedOrdertableHeaderView release];
[TransferedOrderTableHeaderLabel release];    }
-(void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
-(void)reloadNewOrderTable
{
    [self initializeTableData];
    [self.newOrderTableViewController initializeTableData];
    [newOrderTabelView reloadData];
}
@end
```

sorry if the code is messed up. the problem occurs at

```
NSDate* orderDate = order.Date;
```

where order comes from SalesOrder which has an NSDate in it, this NSDate is set in another place where the customer confirms the order, the thing is when the customer confirms the order, the date that will be saved in my SalesOrder is correct, but when I'm trying to assign it in the above code, it goes 1 day back... probably I'm making a mistake and missing some simple fact here, thanks in advance for the help.

P.S: I'm also showing the oder date to customer in some other places (list of orders) and the date in there is correct.

---

**Edit:** Nice catch Hot Licks, the values I'm getting there are information related to the order, it appears the problem is in below code when I'm assigning the date `NSString` to `NSDate` using `dateFromString`:

```
[NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"];                
NSString *orderDateStr=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];    
NSDate *orderDate=[formatter dateFromString:orderDateStr];
```

the `orderDateStr` shows the correct date of order, but `orderDate` shows the day before. I've never encounter such a thing before, any idea ? :)

Comment: Post some code of where you are getting/creating the order object.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I have removed the first two lines (I'm new, thanks for helping and I have this situation) of your question. Without these 2 lines it'll be easier to see the important parts of your question on the overview page. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: sure Nick, I'll post some codes as soon as I get home.

Comment: Sorry fluchtpunkt and thanks for the editing.

Comment: The question is, what value are you getting here: `NSArray* tNewSalesOrderArr=[dataSalesOrder selectSalesOrdersforSalesPerson:appDelegate.loggedInSalesPerson IsUploaded:NO IsDeleted:NO];`, and where are you getting it from?

Comment: I've updated the the answer. can you please check and see if you understand this problem ? it's kinda confusing me .. :\

Comment: I wonder if your date format covers the +0000 at the end.Try something like `[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];` before parsing.

Comment: @ott-- that was exactly what was wrong, thank you so much for your help, now it's working perfectly. thanx a million. 
P.S: do you know how can I accept your comment as the correct answer ?

Comment: I can answer with that comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if your date format covers the +0000 at the end.Try something like [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]]; before parsing.

Comment: cheers mate :) thanks again. I'll make sure to give you +1 later when I can :)